# Kafka Configure PKCS12 `ssl.keystore.location=user.p12` without access to local file system

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-flink, kafka-consumer-api

I can successfully connect to an SSL secured Kafka cluster with the following client properties:

```
security.protocol=SSL
ssl.truststore.type=PKCS12
ssl.truststore.location=ca.p12
ssl.truststore.password=<redacted>
ssl.keystore.type=PKCS12
ssl.keystore.location=user.p12
ssl.keystore.password=<redacted>
```

However, I’m writing a Java app that is running in a managed cloud environment, where I don’t have access to the file system.  So I can’t just give it a local file path to .p12 files.

Are there any other alternatives, like using loading from S3, or from memory, or from a JVM classpath resource?

Specifically, this is a Flink app running on Amazon's Kinesis Analytics Managed Flink cluster service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use alternate settings to provide the files dynamically without going the way around of dumping it in the file system.

**ssl.truststore.certificates**

> Trusted certificates in the format specified by 'ssl.truststore.type'. Default SSL engine factory supports only PEM format with X.509 certificates.

**ssl.keystore.key**

> Certificate chain in the format specified by 'ssl.keystore.type'. Default SSL engine factory supports only PEM format with a list of X.509 certificates

For example, see samples in https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-651+-+Support+PEM+format+for+SSL+certificates+and+private+key#KIP651SupportPEMformatforSSLcertificatesandprivatekey-ProposedChanges

```
ssl.keystore.certificate.chain=-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE----- \
MIIC4jCCAcqgAwIBAgIIJHw42Lu1+w8wDQYJKoZIhvcNAQEFBQAwJDEPMA0GA1UE \
AwwGY2xpZW50MREwDwYDVQQKDAhBIGNsaWVudDAeFw0yMDA4MDMwOTU4MTZaFw0y \
MDA5MDIwOTU4MTZaMCQxDzANBgNVBAMMBmNsaWVudDERMA8GA1UECgwIQSBjbGll \
bnQwggEiMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4IBDwAwggEKAoIBAQCwTUf499MROpsz8LFr \
EOZEvUH6e1qks6AJEWjD7BY/SmwRijNPAaJhHaogYaVPrDEmFfexZDVhtc4eDkDI \
rW6+ZlkpNZupkINCR4R49f7JCjFz6rwGl4lSpa3mIhkXS/ZD0pjCYB9t2xBuTWVq \
ap40WqbQDsJHNH+9V/nzktX0ZOB6AgUuzFwLu3YDKS8XFD5TAdZKIu8rtxFzL1Uo \
HmiWFU9EoHROs23xJn7jCEOBq3L2b5IEE/ZHZVw/ooi/jJIID21bkiI731RWOoE3 \
ClEsh7CQHWlXwyoJmMP2dZrXbERpZclH0ozb5JJwJiMtB1uxUiD3wKF/rlcfRAcZ \
AR4vAgMBAAGjGDAWMBQGA1UdEQQNMAuCCWxvY2FsaG9zdDANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQUF \
AAOCAQEAOqNAWknyUljdFeC/O5fDwoGYqHJY3dkinhjfiDEQm+RLLli64xjlNyRJ \
u4ZMHqEE4yQBnQGFxHkKIcA/poDgntSJrSFsfnpHzZJ5kz5zQdNDT9BYQIPWqoe2 \
0plNB6NjZeUn2OH+hAJIbclye0PXMrLwnDVUOJPS9xnlfgbrvIM0HCjtG95oeWv4 \
VLLOKaxiNYEX0xx9fT/lKjnqgi7OPAMTvfp5y1t4BCoe/43o8Pd0Ih2hdgVE6rLn \
mxEaTdlbQNp1ju70Ztl3NNt17+tceq0VbfTRI1xufTB5dCPWeeg0ekC9jMMs42R+ \
PiGYp7h8A3hRC5m8pYnKLSJp5ymITg== \
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
 
ssl.keystore.key=-----BEGIN ENCRYPTED PRIVATE KEY----- \
... \
-----END ENCRYPTED PRIVATE KEY--
```

This method of providing the keys is more convenient when keys are not packaged or static.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, you can download whatever you want from wherever before you give a properties object to a KafkaConsumer. However, the user running the Java process will need some access to the local filesystem in order to download files.

I think packaging the files as part of your application JAR makes more sense, however, I don't know an easy way to refer to a classpath resource as if it were a regular filesystem path. If the code runs in YARN cluster, you can try using `yarn.provided.lib.dirs` option when submitting as well

Answer (score 0):

I used a workaround tempoarily, upload your certificates to a fileshare and make your application, during initialization, dowload the certificates from the file share and save it to the location of choice like /home/site/ca.p12 then kakfa properties should read
...
ssl.truststore.location=/home/site/ca.p12
...

Here are few lines of code to help you download and save your certificate.

```
// Create the Azure Files client.
    CloudFileClient fileClient = storageAccount.createCloudFileClient();
// Get a reference to the file share
    CloudFileShare share = fileClient.getShareReference("[SHARENAME]");
// Get a reference to the root directory for the share.
    CloudFileDirectory rootDir = share.getRootDirectoryReference();
// Get a reference to the directory where the file to be deleted is in
    CloudFileDirectory containerDir = rootDir.getDirectoryReference("[DIRECTORY]");
    CloudFile file = containerDir.getFileReference("[FILENAME]");
file.downloadToFile("/home/site/ca.p12");
```